# I want to run "python manage.py makemigrations ". Got error "password authentication failed""No changes detected"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to run:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-136:~/easy_django_repo$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

And got this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:143: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "diEvaR6s52EqJv"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "diEvaR6s52EqJv"

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

I changed password for user and os:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-136:~/easy_django_repo$ sudo -u postgres psql
Password for user postgres:
psql (14.6 (Ubuntu 14.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#ALTER USER diEvaR6s52EqJv WITH PASSWORD '#####';
```

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-136:~$ sudo passwd postgres
New password:
```

And I ran:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-136:/etc/postgresql/14/main$ sudo -u postgres psql
Password for user postgres:
```

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-136:/etc/postgresql/14/main$  psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
```

Got error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I can't understand what do I have to do. Can anyone give me some advice? Almost struggling for a week.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the DB password should be set in the `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Also verify the python version your EC2 instance is using.  By default, it is:

```
       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-83-218 ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-83-218 ~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.16
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-83-218 ~]$
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I could't make it. So I deleted and am making database again.